# Trigger Jenkins job via Slack command - 403_client_error

Tags: jenkins, slack

I'm trying to do a pretty simple thing I believe - trigger a Jenkins job from a slash command in slack. I want to type `/dump` in slack and that should trigger particular jenkins job. I'm using [Slack Slash command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) to achieve this and the setup is very simple - type command, type URL, select POST/GET method.

I tried two methods - first was to use Build Authorization Token Root Plugin following [this tutorial](https://sonnguyen.ws/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-slack/) - in this case I configured Slack slash command to make GET request on the URL: `http://jenkins_url:8080/job/db-dump-setup/build?token=MY_TOKEN` - If I put the URL to my browser, the job gets triggered, if I run the `/dump` command, slack responds with:

```
slackbot [3:41 PM]
Darn - that slash command didn't work (error message: `403_client_error`). Manage the command at text.
```

The second approach I tried was following [this tutorial](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-selenium-webdriver-how-to-trigger-automated-test-execution-from-slack/). In this case I created new user in Jenkins and got API token. When running this command from my terminal: `curl -X POST http://USER:TOKEN@slack_url:8080/job/db-dump-setup/build`, the job gets again triggered, however when configuring the Slack slash command with the same URL and making POST request, I get the same error:  `403_client_error`

I tried to google this specific error but didn't find anything useful, also there are no more details for the error or any logs which could help me to troubleshoot this further.

Anyone run into something similar and knows how could I get this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this so answering my own question in a case someone else runs into this. In order to make the first case work (Using the GET request), I had to enable the "Allow anonymous read access" in Jenkins, in Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security as per the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: @Pert Hecko It didnt work for me. Anything else we can do?

Comment: @SobhitSharma check the reply above for the authenticated call, that works for me just fine

Comment: Allowing anonymous user is not the right thing to do I guess.

Comment: After doing this, Jenkins is not letting me login to the application

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to enable anonymous access.Your jenkins requires authentication. Update your url like http://user:auth-token@jenkins-host:port.Auth token can be generated at the following URL JENKINS_HOST/me/configure

Comment: Thanks @karan! Yes, we actually had some security concerns about the anonymous access to jenkins few months ago and are using the authenticated URL since then - something like this works for our slash commands: `https://<user>:<auth_token>@<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/build?token=<token>`

Comment: How does this work if the Jenkins is SAML authenticated ?